# I'm trying to style <select> tag in html using css. It works in Firefox properly but not in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, select

I'm trying to style  tag in html using css. It works in Firefox properly but not in chrome. Here is the code i use in styling forms. After referring some through internet I used !important; command along with this style sheet. But it did not worked.

```
.style {
   display: block;
   border: none;
   color: #333;
   background: transparent;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
   padding: 5px 2px 0 2px;
   width:300px;
   font-size: 14;
   color:#FFF; 
 }

.style:focus{  
   outline: none;
   border-color: #51CBEE;
 }
```

Comment: what is ur html look like?

Comment: @Sanath: don't you know how a `<select>` will look like? the HTML for a `<select>` will not influence the styling

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13968900/703717)

Answer (score 2):

simply? you can't.

Firefox allows you to do some styling on a `<select>`, but is not consistence along browsers.

You should go for a JavaScript masking solution if you really want the `<select>` to be styled crossbrowser.

Maybe [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't yet a cross-browser compatible route of styling form elements with CSS: it's not usually left to the designer to have control over their appearance/behaviour so form elements are notoriously difficult to style. Many browsers specifically do not allow you to style them at all!

If you need to get a consistent look across all browsers, the only route is to use JavaScript to replace the form element in-view with stylised HTML elements.

Here's an article that lists a few of the options available for you: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: Thanx for the insight I'll look forward with this.